# UK Visa refusal and ban for 10 years (false documents). Can I apply for Australia?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, australia

My wife applied for the UK academic and I was the dependent. Our application got refused and we got banned for 10 years — false documents. We didn't reply to the refusals. Now 10 years have passed and I want to apply for Australia to get the MSc degree. My wife will be dependent this time. Can someone please let me know the possibilities for this matter?

Comment: Any advice we can give will work only if you are a genuine visitor. If your intent is to overstay the visa then the advice will not be helpful to you.

Answer (score 8):

The Australian form will ask if you have **ever** been removed, deported, or excluded from any country, Australia or otherwise. If so, they ask for the details.

- The fact that the UK banned you will reduce your chances for an Australian visa but it will not make it impossible.
- The fact that the ban has expired will make it a little better, but it will not make the problem go away completely.

We cannot predict your chances, but they will look very closely at any documents you submit this time.

---

This won't help chathuranga after the fact, but others who are reading this should note that just **one** ban or deportation by a major country can follow you for the rest of your life. Read the visa forms carefully and tell the truth.